# Symbol placed with line-center doesn't rotate as the map rotates

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm having a problem rotating an image with property `symbol-placement` set to `line-center`.
This is what it looks like

[image]

Removing the property half-solve the issue; the icon rotate as I rotate the map, but they position at the start of the line, and it's not what I'm trying to do.

[image]

The definition of my layer is:

```
{
  "id": "my_symbol",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": "XXXX",
  "source-layer": "XXXXXXX",
  "minzoom": 19,
  "layout": {
    "symbol-placement": "line-center",
    "icon-size": {
      "stops": [
        [20, 0.2],
        [21, 0.1],
        [22, 0.3],
        [23, 0.5],
        [24, 0.7]
      ]
    },
    "icon-image": [
      "concat",
      "edge_",
      ["get", "status_list"]
    ],
    "icon-allow-overlap": true
  }
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this behaviour only by the layer's definition.
I tried looking for a solution, here on SO and on some other sites but I haven't found anything that would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set your icon rotation with `icon-rotation-alignment`

setting it to `viewport` will fix the icon rotation to your viewport while setting it to `map` won't rotate it

[image]

i'm sorry the gif is hard to see!

```
{
  "id": "my_symbol",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": "XXXX",
  "source-layer": "XXXXXXX",
  "minzoom": 19,
  "layout": {
    "symbol-placement": "line-center",
    "icon-size": {
      "stops": [
        [20, 0.2],
        [21, 0.1],
        [22, 0.3],
        [23, 0.5],
        [24, 0.7]
      ]
    },
    "icon-image": [
      "concat",
      "edge_",
      ["get", "status_list"]
    ],
    "icon-allow-overlap": true,
    "symbol-placement": "line-center",
    "icon-rotation-alignment": "viewport"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It does solve my problem.